# Multiple appstore application versions - regular and certified

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, versions

I have to get a certification for my app for government customers. So there will be two (similar) apps in the app store - regular (development) version and a certified (frozen) version.

My question is - what should be different in the new app?
- new app name (e.g. My Certified App)
- new bundle id (com.mycompany.my-certified-app)
- new push certificate for the server?
- new images?

I have never submitted a lite/full version app before, maybe this type of thing is all too common.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a different bundle ID to make two apps (they'll need to have different names in iTunes too, but the name on the homescreen / in the project can be the same).

You can create a new target for your app, and that will give you a second info.plist. That lets you specify different bundle IDs for the two versions without needing to physically copy and paste the whole project.

However you may have trouble getting this approved by Apple if both apps are identical apart from the version number / certified status.

If one app is just for testing, can't you use TestFlight or something similar to allow your customers to try the app in beta before it's certified?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding "*- Certified*" to your app name.  There are plenty of examples in the iTunes store of full versions, and "*- Lite*" versions.

In addition to the name, it is customary to have the app icon reflect the different versions.

See[RoboKill](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/robokill-rescue-titan-prime/id399166482?mt=8), and [RoboKill Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/robokill-lite/id408858614?mt=8) as one example.